# unable to create a list view to filter my Wiki Pages which contain the following text 'T:\' inside their "Page Content" field

Tags: 2013, development, list-view, caml, wiki-pages

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection inside our sharepoint on-premises 2013. and i want to create a list view which shows all the wiki pages which contain the following "T:\" inside their "Page Content". So i created a new list view, and i define the following filter:-
[image]

but the list view will not show any items, although we have around 200 pages which contain text as follow:-

> T:\Support\Unit\Documents
>
> t:\customers\

so can anyone advice on this please?

Also if i define the following filter, i will not get anything:-
[image]

now if i just remove the "T:" i will get results!!
[image]

but in my case i only want to get pages which contain this text "T:\" ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After view the wiki page source, I notice the ":" is replaced as `&#58;` in the page source, you can type the filter as Page Content contains  "`T&#58;\`" to achieve your requirement.

Comment: ok it worked for me.. but for curiosity how did you know that the `:` will be replaced as  `&#58;` .. also do you have a list of such characters?

Comment: I just open the page and right click->view page source, find "\customers\" text, and notice the ":" display as ""&# 5 8;", I didn't find any official documentation that states the list of characters.